# Transform bytes to pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, byte, fs

I am able to save the pdf now, but when I open it everything is blank. He even managed to save the number of pages he has

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(data)
try {
   fs.writeFileSync('data.pdf', buffer)   //'a+' is append mode 
   console.log("File written successfully");
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: When using the `Buffer.from(data)` what is `data`? Is it a buffer, byte array, String? It'd be helpful for the community if you ask a question like [StackOverflow recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and share more code or a reproducible code at least.

Comment: it comes as bytes
data = bytes